# Trouble in redirecting page after login and logout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am working on a app using nodejs, angular, cassandra which contains login and logout.

when i try to login then i have to **refresh** to go to **home** page after clicking **login** button.
and when i click on **logout** button then again have to refresh to go to the **login/signup** page.

this is **logout Controller** (logoutCtrl.js)

```
angular.module('app').controller('logoutCtrl', ['$scope', 'LogoutService',
    function($scope, LogoutService) {
        $scope.logout = function() {
            LogoutService();
        };
    }
]);
```

this is **logout service**

```
    angular.module('app').factory('LogoutService', function($http, $location) {
    return function() {
        $http.get('/logout').then(function(result) {
            $location.url('/');
        });
    };
});
```

this is **routes.js** which is distroying the session after clicking on logout

```
app.get('/logout', function(req, res, next) {
    req.session.destroy(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
});
```

this is the  **home.html** file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><title>MyApp<title></head>
<body>
   <div ng-controller="logoutCtrl">
       <button class="btn pull-right" ng-click="logout()">logout</button>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

how to redirect the **login** and **logout** without needing and refresh

Comment: use window.location.url() in place of   $location.url('/');.

Comment: not working, actully after clicking e.g. logout button process of session distroy takes place correctly but url doen't chnages hence seems like empty click unless you refresh the page.

Comment: $http.get('/logout') returns OK status ..??

Comment: than try $location.path('/');..

Comment: @squirioid   see the updates route part. yes $http.get('/logout') is activating route part which distroys the session so yeah it's returning ok

Comment: Great:-) SO in that case use $location.path('/');

Comment: have done in above posted question already. it stills need a refresh to complete the task

Comment: can u please provide more code? the error seems to be somewhere else maybe show your client side routing and your redirecting after login

Comment: i just need an appropriate method to refresh page in the logout service when response is successful  @ below mention place
$location.ulr('/')

Comment: location.reload(true) worked in service.